# Mysql Query for breaking unix time stamp into periods

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table named posts in which there are 3 fields like :

- post_id   (int, autoincrement, primary)
- post_text (varchar 200)
- post_time (int)

I am using the following mysql query to insert data into the above mentioned table :

```
INSERT INTO `posts` 
  (`post_id`, `post_text`, `post_time`) 
VALUES 
  (NULL, '324324234', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now I am trying to retrieve the data based on weeks from the above table. Say, I want to display the number of posts inserted in database every week (Mon - Sun).  I know I can do it via YearWeek function in mysql but it's not working properly.

Comment: What are you trying and what happens?

Comment: I think it's working perfectly fine if I GROUP BY :

YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%m-%d'),1)

any idea how can I get the start and end day of the week based on unix time stamp in mysql query ?

say mysql unix time stamp is : 1303367094  

i know i can do it by php but it will be great if someone can point me to right mysql query to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

You stored the date/time as a unix timestamp, so you need to convert it into a DATETIME before you can use YEARWEEK - use:

```
  SELECT YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.post_time)),
         COUNT(*) AS numPosts
    FROM POSTS p
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.post_time))
```

DATE_FORMAT would provide the ability to customize the year/week value.

### Reference:

- [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)
- [YEARWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)
- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

@OMGPonies --

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.post_time)) AS yw,
     COUNT(*) AS numPosts
FROM POSTS p
GROUP BY yw;
```

will run faster (probably -- certainly no slower).

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are the only databases that allow accessing column aliases before the ORDER BY (to my knowledge).  Otherwise, there's no difference between my query and this - it won't run faster.  Don't mistake speed for query caching.

Comment: @OMGPonies -- MySQL was called out in the question (and I don't think YEARWEEK is portable either).  And are you saying the query optimizer evaluates two expressions (one from the group-by and one from the select clause) and if it can prove they are always equal, doesn't do the recalc?  Maybe if you restrict it to a character-to-character comparison (or some kind of post-parse comparison to eliminate case and white-space differences) then maybe, maybe.  Even so, better to do it my way: it's more legible.

Comment: Your "readability" gives false impressions about SQL in general, which leads to "why can't I..." questions when people try to use it on other databases.  All your query does is save typing.

Comment: @OMGPonies -- unsupported assertions are no substitute for evidence.  Are you that the query optimizer *does* analyze the two expressions or that the evaluation of the second expression is free?  As for the "why can't I" problems -- those are universal (why *can't* I use a temporary table in a self-join in MySQL); I don't see any reason to sacrifice readability **and** waste CPU in futile attempt to avoid it.

Comment: It's your belief that using a column alias in the GROUP BY provides performance improvement - you prove it.  If the explain plan is identical between the two, then my assertion stands that your alternative only saves typing.

Comment: The explain plan *will* be the same between the two queries: the same rows and columns are needed.  Nonetheless, the server still has to calculate the expression twice: once in the query and once when generating the view.

Comment: works pefectly fine... thanks :) anyway I can fetch the start (Mon) and end date (Sun) of each week in mysql query itself ?